# What's the principle to define an interface with dependencies?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, method-signature

Which dependency should locate in a method signature as a param and which should not? Since we have IoC container like spring, most of the dependencies could get injected through it.

For `java.util.concurrent.Executor`:

```
public interface Executor {

    void execute(Runnable command);
}
```

The interface could be

```
public interface Executor {

    void execute();
}
```

Another case, in a traditional web application, a counter may be written like this

```
public interface CounterManager {

    int query(User user);//user is a runtime information
}
```

Since spring offers request scope, `User` could be injected either.

```
public interface Counter {

    int query();//get user through Injected
}
```

Is there some principle or best practice to make the choice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some principle or best practice to make the choice? Thanks!

You can use "Coding complexity rule" as a guidance. Everything that lowers code complexity in both short-term and a long-term way is good. Everything that raises it is bad.

If you start injecting everything with a use of DI container, you will end up with a DI settings file of Merriam-Webster Dictionary in size.

If something is so plain simple, that can be just passed as a parameter to a method, why to complicate things with a DI container?

Comment: Is there some excellent tool to measure code complexity or coupling?

Comment: @Anderson Plenty: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/java-code-quality-tools-overview.html